# Facebook login using Mobile Client Access in Cordova app

Tags: facebook, cordova, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I want to add social login in a Cordova application using Mobile Client Access. When I'm installing the Cordova plugins as detailed in the documentation I get this error:

> Failed to install 'bms-core':CordovaError: Uh oh!
>   "/Users/abc/work/workspace-atlantic/BMS/platforms/android/src/com/ibm/mobilefirstplatform/clientsdk/cordovaplugins/core/CDVBMSClient.java" already exists!
>       at copyNewFile (/Users/abc/work/workspace-atlantic/BMS/platforms/android/cordova/lib/pluginHandlers.js:232:15)
>       at handlers.source-file.install (/Users/abc/work/workspace-atlantic/BMS/platforms/android/cordova/lib/pluginHandlers.js:37:17)
>       at Object.ActionStack.process (/Users/abc/work/workspace-atlantic/BMS/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ActionStack.js:56:25)
>       at PluginManager.doOperation (/Users/abc/work/workspace-atlantic/BMS/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/PluginManager.js:117:20)
>       at PluginManager.addPlugin (/Users/abc/work/workspace-atlantic/BMS/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/PluginManager.js:147:17)
>       at Api.addPlugin (/Users/abc/work/workspace-atlantic/BMS/platforms/android/cordova/Api.js:198:10)

Is it necessary to install both `bms-core` and `ibm-mfp-core` plugins or just `ibm-mfp-core`? How much from Facebook's user profile I will be able to access?

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova plugin `bms-core` is the new version of `ibm-mfp-core` which is being deprecated.

So only put `bms-core` in your project.

After you connect, you'll have access to a token to access to your protected backend resources and the ability to get your user's identity (id and display name). You can use the Facebook Developer Console to manage user roles for your app.